# css repeating background height and absolute positioning

Tags: html, css, layout

I have a container with a repeating image that i want to fill 100% of the available height. Some of the inner divs have their :after pseudo elements absolutely positioned so i can get the borders the way i need them. This is causing an issue with the repeating background of the main container.

Please visit this link and scroll to the end of the page - 
http://www.mariage-graham-audrey.com/static.html

Can anyone suggest a possible solution for this ?

Answer (score 1):

Just a workaround but try to add larger bottom padding to layout like this:

```
.layout {
  ...
  padding-bottom: 180px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just saw your CSS and I think by adding this you would be able to get a full page background :

```
  background: white url("/bootstrap/assets/images/pattern.png") 0 0;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 30px 0;
  min-height: 100%;
```

Just edit the " width:100%; " thats all.

Answer (score 0):

Please Replace your style for layout div with this. It will work

```css
.layout{
  background: white url("/bootstrap/assets/images/pattern.png") 0 0;
  width: 100%;  /* add 100% width*/
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 0 150px 0;  /*change padding with this*/
  min-height: 100%;
}
```